# Table inside a td to stack vertically on mobile devices using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using VS 2012 with bootstrap. The "TD" on table 1 are datalist and another table. I want them to stack vertically on small devices.

[image]

Comment: show  your code ............ Used to media query

Comment: Since you are using bootstrap you can use media query based on size (height and width) of mobile device to change the position of TR/TD.

Comment: is this it? @media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dl-horizontal dt {
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: left;
    text-align: right;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .dl-horizontal dd {
    margin-left: 180px;
  }
}